# Get the return value from a WCF Restful service which is POST method

Tags: rest, wcf

I want to know how to get the return value from a WCF Restful service which is POST method. I am able to get the return value if it is a GET method. In GET method, webClient.DownloadString(url); is returning the result. But in case of POST method, webClient.UploadString(url, "POST", data); is not returning the result, it is just invoking the web service.

I have seen many samples, people are just calling the WCF service post method with UploadString() method and assuming that it returns success. But I want to check the return value and based on that show appropriate message.

```
//----------------------------------- WCF RESTful service -----------------------------------
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAppService
{       
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ValidateVisitPIN", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool ValidateVisitPIN(VisitPinRequest visitPinRequest);
}

public class AppService : IAppService
{
    public bool ValidateVisitPIN(VisitPinRequest visitPinRequest)
    {
        //......
        if(visitPinRequest.visitPin == 100)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
//----------------------------------- WCF client application -----------------------------------
//POST method
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    VisitPinRequest visitPinRequest = new VisitPinRequest();
    visitPinRequest.VisitPin = txtVisitPIN.Text;

    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(VisitPinRequest));
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
    ser.WriteObject(mem, visitPinRequest);
    string url = webServiceURL + "ValidateVisitPIN";

    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
    webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var returnString = webClient.UploadString(url, "POST", data);
}

//Get method
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string url = webServiceURL + "ValidateVisitPIN/" + txtVisitPIN.Text;
    string outputString = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    MessageBox.Show(outputString);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this:

```
private static T Call<T>(string url, string body, int timeOut = 20)
{
    var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Timeout = timeOut * 1000;
    request.ContentLength = contentBytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Accept = "application/json";

    using (var requestWritter = request.GetRequestStream())
        requestWritter.Write(contentBytes, 0, (int)request.ContentLength);

    var responseString = string.Empty;
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        reader.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = timeOut * 1000;
        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```
        var input = new
        {
            test1="",
            .
            .
            .
        }
        var output = Call<bool>(url, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input));
```

Comment: The web service without any parameter works fine. But I need to pass json string to the web service. I am getting below Bad request error (400): The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. Please tell me how to pass the parameters

Comment: well. problem is with your input. how serialize your input?